# client side validation only shows up on one of two nested simple_fields_for

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, client-side-validation

I've got a simple_form_for with two nested simple_fields_for in it. I have installed the gem client_side_validations to generate client side validations. But this works only for one of my two nested simple_fields_for. I updated client_side_validations to the latest version (3.2.6), but that doesn't helped. I played a little bit with ryan bates railscast example app client_side_validation #263 trying to get it to work there. There worked the same setup as expected. But in my app not. I striped nearly everything away in my app to identify the error. Then it looked very similar to the working railscast app. But the validation in the simple_fields_for :yearkontakts form doesn't show up.The JavaScript seems to be generated properly. As far as I can see there is no cause for this behavior. Is there anybody who can help me to find a solution?

Thanks in advance!

This is the generated html:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/schools" class="simple_form form-horizontal" data-validate="true" id="new_school" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="JWKD6YuWm/474gjPivE2h3e7+sKhyeSby/d6OX0/7M0=" /></div>
  <p>School</p>
  <div class="control-group string required school_name"><label class="string required control-label" for="school_name"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Name</label><div class="controls"><input class="string required" id="school_name" name="school[name]" size="50" type="text" /></div></div>
  <div class="control-group string required school_street"><label class="string required control-label" for="school_street"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Street</label><div class="controls"><input class="string required" id="school_street" name="school[street]" size="50" type="text" /></div></div>
  <div class="control-group string required school_plz"><label class="string required control-label" for="school_plz"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Plz</label><div class="controls"><input class="string required" id="school_plz" name="school[plz]" size="50" type="text" /></div></div>
  <div class="control-group string required school_city"><label class="string required control-label" for="school_city"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> City</label><div class="controls"><input class="string required" id="school_city" name="school[city]" size="50" type="text" /></div></div>
  <div class="control-group select required school_state_id"><label class="select required control-label" for="school_state_id"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> State</label><div class="controls"><select class="select required" id="school_state_id" name="school[state_id]"><option value=""></option>
<option value="2">Baden-Württemberg</option>
<option value="3">Bayern</option>
<option value="4">Berlin</option>
<option value="5">Brandenburg</option>
<option value="6">Bremen</option>
<option value="7">Hamburg</option>
<option value="8">Hessen</option>
<option value="9">Mecklenburg-Vorpommern</option>
<option value="10">Niedersachsen</option>
<option value="11">Nordrhein-Westfalen</option>
<option value="12">Rheinland-Pfalz</option>
<option value="13">Saarland</option>
<option value="14">Sachsen</option>
<option value="15">Sachsen-Anhalt</option>
<option value="16">Schleswig-Holstein</option>
<option value="17">Thüringen</option></select></div></div>
  <p>
    Year</p>

    <div class="control-group select required school_years_jahrgang_id"><label class="select required control-label" for="school_years_attributes_0_jahrgang_id"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Jahrgang</label><div class="controls"><select class="select required" id="school_years_attributes_0_jahrgang_id" name="school[years_attributes][0][jahrgang_id]"><option value=""></option>
<option value="4">2012 / 2013</option>
<option value="5">2013 / 2014</option></select></div></div>
    <div class="control-group select required school_years_count_id"><label class="select required control-label" for="school_years_attributes_0_count_id"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Count</label><div class="controls"><select class="select required" id="school_years_attributes_0_count_id" name="school[years_attributes][0][count_id]"><option value=""></option>
<option value="2">weniger als 40</option>
<option value="3">40 - 60</option>
<option value="4">60 - 80</option>
<option value="5">80 - 100</option>
<option value="6">100 - 120</option>
<option value="7">120 - 140</option>
<option value="8">140 - 160</option>
<option value="9">mehr als 160</option></select></div></div>
    <div class="control-group select required school_years_schuldauer_id"><label class="select required control-label" for="school_years_attributes_0_schuldauer_id"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Schuldauer</label><div class="controls"><select class="select required" id="school_years_attributes_0_schuldauer_id" name="school[years_attributes][0][schuldauer_id]"><option value=""></option>
<option value="2">12 Jahre</option>
<option value="3">13 Jahre</option>
<option value="4">12 und 13 Jahre</option></select></div></div>
    <p>
      Contact</p>

      <div class="control-group select required school_years_yearkontakts_sex"><label class="select required control-label" for="school_years_attributes_0_yearkontakts_attributes_0_geschlecht_id"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Sex</label><div class="controls"><select class="select required" id="school_years_attributes_0_yearkontakts_attributes_0_geschlecht_id" name="school[years_attributes][0][yearkontakts_attributes][0][geschlecht_id]"><option value=""></option>
<option value="2">Herr</option>
<option value="4">Frau</option></select></div></div>
      <div class="control-group string required school_years_yearkontakts_vorname"><label class="string required control-label" for="school_years_attributes_0_yearkontakts_attributes_0_vorname"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Vorname</label><div class="controls"><input class="string required" id="school_years_attributes_0_yearkontakts_attributes_0_vorname" name="school[years_attributes][0][yearkontakts_attributes][0][vorname]" size="50" type="text" /></div></div>
      <div class="control-group string required school_years_yearkontakts_nachname"><label class="string required control-label" for="school_years_attributes_0_yearkontakts_attributes_0_nachname"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Nachname</label><div class="controls"><input class="string required" id="school_years_attributes_0_yearkontakts_attributes_0_nachname" name="school[years_attributes][0][yearkontakts_attributes][0][nachname]" size="50" type="text" /></div></div>
      <div class="control-group email required school_years_yearkontakts_email"><label class="email required control-label" for="school_years_attributes_0_yearkontakts_attributes_0_email"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Email</label><div class="controls"><input class="string email required" id="school_years_attributes_0_yearkontakts_attributes_0_email" name="school[years_attributes][0][yearkontakts_attributes][0][email]" size="50" type="email" /></div></div>
      <div class="control-group text optional school_years_yearkontakts_notizen"><label class="text optional control-label" for="school_years_attributes_0_yearkontakts_attributes_0_notizen">Notizen</label><div class="controls"><textarea class="text optional" cols="40" id="school_years_attributes_0_yearkontakts_attributes_0_notizen" name="school[years_attributes][0][yearkontakts_attributes][0][notizen]" rows="20"></textarea></div></div>
  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create School" />
</form>
```

And this the generated JavaScript:

```
<script>//<![CDATA[
if(window.ClientSideValidations===undefined)window.ClientSideValidations={};window.ClientSideValidations.disabled_validators=[];window.ClientSideValidations.number_format={"separator":".","delimiter":","};if(window.ClientSideValidations.patterns===undefined)window.ClientSideValidations.patterns = {};window.ClientSideValidations.patterns.numericality=/^(-|\+)?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d*)?$/;if(window.ClientSideValidations.forms===undefined)window.ClientSideValidations.forms={};window.ClientSideValidations.forms['new_school'] = {"type":"SimpleForm::FormBuilder","error_class":"help-inline","error_tag":"span","wrapper_error_class":"error","wrapper_tag":"div","wrapper_class":"control-group","wrapper":"bootstrap","validators":{"school[years_attributes][][yearkontakts_attributes][][geschlecht_id]":{"presence":[{"message":"can't be blank"}]},"school[years_attributes][][yearkontakts_attributes][][vorname]":{"presence":[{"message":"can't be blank"}]},"school[years_attributes][][yearkontakts_attributes][][nachname]":{"presence":[{"message":"can't be blank"}]},"school[years_attributes][][yearkontakts_attributes][][email]":{"presence":[{"message":"can't be blank"}]},"school[years_attributes][][jahrgang_id]":{"presence":[{"message":"can't be blank"}]},"school[years_attributes][][count_id]":{"presence":[{"message":"can't be blank"}]},"school[years_attributes][][schuldauer_id]":{"presence":[{"message":"can't be blank"}]},"school[name]":{"length":[{"messages":{"minimum":"is too short (minimum is 4 characters)"},"allow_blank":true,"minimum":4}],"presence":[{"message":"can't be blank"}]},"school[street]":{"presence":[{"message":"can't be blank"}]},"school[plz]":{"presence":[{"message":"can't be blank"}]},"school[city]":{"presence":[{"message":"can't be blank"}]},"school[state_id]":{"presence":[{"message":"can't be blank"}]}}};
//]]></script>
```

This is my school_controller:

```
class SchoolsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /schools/new
  # GET /schools/new.json
  def new
    @school = School.new
    @year = @school.years.build
    @yearkontakt = @year.yearkontakts.build
    @standardformat = @school.standardformats.build
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @school }
    end
  end

end
```

This my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @school, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal"}, :validate => true do |s| %>
  <p>School</p>
  <%= s.input :name %>
  <%= s.input :street %>
  <%= s.input :plz %>
  <%= s.input :city%>
  <%= s.input :state_id, collection: State.all %>
  <p>
    Year</p>
  <%= s.simple_fields_for :years, :year do |y| %>
    <%= y.input :jahrgang_id, collection: Yearname.yearnames_aktuell_future %>
    <%= y.input :count_id, collection: Count.all%>
    <%= y.input :schuldauer_id, collection: Length.all %>
    <p>
      Contact</p>
    <%= y.simple_fields_for :yearkontakts, :yearkontakt do |yk| %>
      <%= yk.association :sex %>
      <%= yk.input :vorname %>
      <%= yk.input :nachname %>
      <%= yk.input :email %>
      <%= yk.input :notizen  %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= s.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And here are my three models

school:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :years, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :state
  validates_length_of :name, :minimum => 4, :allow_blank => true
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :street
  validates_presence_of :state_id
  validates_presence_of :plz
  validates_presence_of :city
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :years
end
```

year:

```
class Year < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :yearkontakts, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :count
  belongs_to :yearname, :foreign_key => "jahrgang_id"
  belongs_to :length, :foreign_key => "schuldauer_id"
  belongs_to :school
  validates_presence_of :jahrgang_id
  validates_presence_of :schuldauer_id
  validates_presence_of :count_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :yearkontakts
end
```

yearkontakt:

```
class Yearkontakt < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :sex, :foreign_key => :geschlecht_id
    belongs_to :year
    validates_presence_of :vorname
    validates_presence_of :nachname
    validates_presence_of :geschlecht_id
    validates_presence_of :email
end
```

Update (2013-08-20):

I tried to nest another simple_fields_for form on the same level as :yearcontacts. The new form showed no client side validation, too! Seems to me that there is no problem with the yearcontact model.

Another finding was, that If I'm changing the simple_fields_for block from:

```
<%= y.simple_fields_for :yearkontakts, :yearkontakt do |yk| %>
   <%= yk.association :sex %>
   <%= yk.input :vorname %>
   <%= yk.input :nachname %>
   <%= yk.input :email %>
   <%= yk.input :notizen  %>
<% end %>
```

to

```
<%= y.simple_fields_for @yearkontakt do |yk| %>
   <%= yk.association :sex %>
   <%= yk.input :vorname %>
   <%= yk.input :nachname %>
   <%= yk.input :email %>
   <%= yk.input :notizen  %>
<% end %>
```

then the client side validation works. But then the create controller can't identify the @yearkontakt data as nested attributes for @year.

Comment: Your question is pretty special. I see you're from Germany, too, so you could shoot me a quick email (it's in my profile) and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I'm stuck with the same kind of problem. I have a form with nested attributes and multiple `fields_for` inside this form for the child model. The JavaScript generated by the gem only tries to validate `super[sub_attributes][][name]` instead of `super[sub_attributes][0][name]`. Any idea @railsnewbie or @ThomasKlemm ?

Comment: Guys any success on this problem. I am facing the same issue with multiple nested forms.

Comment: With a hint from Thomas Klemm I converted the underlying object with the nested fields into a form object. http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/#form-objects // http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects
That way it worked seamless.